# Third party XML with web DTD transforming to internal DTD

Tags: c#, xslt, local, dtd

I have a third party XML with web DTD looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE orders 
  SYSTEM "http://www.mijnwinkel.nl/DTD/orders_export_v2.dtd">
<orders>
<mail version="2.0" >
  <set id="session" sequence="1" version="1.1" >
    <property id="calc_vat"   
              label="" 
              sequence="0" 
              resource_label="" 
              show_type="" 
              name="" >1</property>
    <property id="emailvendor" 
              label="" 
              sequence="" 
              resource_label="" 
              show_type="" 
              name=""> ... </property>
```

etc...

I developed a XSLT script to transform this to a new XML which is processed in a .Net application.

Problem is that I want this application to work offline, which means that the XSLT should ignore the external DTD and use a local copy of it in the code.

So, my code looks like this:

```
foreach (var file in fileslist)
{
  Message.SendMessage( "Transformeer: "+ file + "....start" );
  CurrentFile = Path.GetFileName(file);

  //Transforming XML using XSL
  var resolver = new XmlUrlResolver
     {
        Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
     };

      // xml content reader            
      var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
           {
              XmlResolver = resolver,
              DtdProcessing = System.Xml.DtdProcessing.Parse
           };
      var xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(); 


      using (Stream strm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EAOrderImportBL.Import.xsl"))
                using (XmlReader xslreader = XmlReader.Create(strm))
                {

                    xslCompiledTransform.Load(xslreader, XsltSettings.Default, resolver);

                }

                var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();

                var reader = XmlReader.Create(file, settings);

                using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(TempPath + @"\" + CurrentFile, xmlSettings))
                {

                    xslCompiledTransform.Transform(reader, w);
                }
                reader.Close();

                Message.SendMessage( "Transformatie: " + file + "....complete" );
            }
        }
```

This works fine , a side of the long processing due to the external link to the DTD.

So, when offline the code line:

```
 xslCompiledTransform.Transform(reader, w);
```

throws an exception about unable to connect/find the external DTD.

Can anybody explain how to change the code, in order that the xslCompiledTransform.Transform method line will just check a copy of the web DTD?

Many thanks in advance , 
Jahwik

Comment: Should I use a custom Resolver?
LocalXMLUrlResolver : XmlUrlResolver...

Comment: Did you try to make a copy of DTD locally and then (before file processing) replace remote link to local one?

Comment: Yes , I have a copy of the DTD local. So you suggest that before the XSL proces, I replace the remote link by a local link?

So, if the original xml has a remote DTD link, there is now way in overruling it by some customUrlResolver? Cause I was aiming at that. I.e. leaving the third party xml untouched and providing the XmlReaderSettings by a custom resolver. But it's not working.
Tnx for the comment!